# How to find radial and tangential force for non-uniform circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, home-experiment

I am currently studying the non-uniform rotational motion of a pulley under the force of a falling weight. If for instance we observe the motion of a black point mass on the pulley with:

$\theta$= initial angle of rotation

$\omega$=initial angular velocity

$vr$= initial radial velocity

$r$= radius

$M_1$= mass 1 hanging from pulley

$M_p$= Mass of Pulley

How can we derive a generalised formula for the tangential force $F_\theta$ and radial force $F_r$ acting on the point mass in terms of the variables above?

[image]

Comment: [Homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093)
are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific 
computations instead of underlying physics concepts. Homework questions can be on-topic when they are useful to a broader 
audience. If you intend to modify your question, please read the links above carefully before editing.

Comment: I know that in this scenario, the net force acting should be the downwards gravitation force $-gM_1$ but I don't know how to relate that to tangential and radial forces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving for such situations, require understanding of both kinematical and rotational dynamics equations.

Here, we let's say our pulley has moment of inertia $I$.

Let's write net force equation for $m_1$
$$m_1g-T=ma$$

For pulley, we can write torque equation:
$$Tr=I\frac{a}{r}\,\,\,\, ,(\text{We used}\, \alpha=\frac{a}{r})$$
Solving both equations we can find acceleration $a$ of our whole system.
Now, here $a$, is actually, tangential acceleration when talking of pulley (Its acting tangentially because of rope). So here we can easily find tangential force acting on black dot: $F_t=ma$.

Now talking, of centripetal force, it would increase with time, as $\omega$ increases due to angular acceleration.
$$\omega'=\omega+\alpha t$$
Hence now:
$$F_c=m(\omega')^2r$$

Comment: Hi , thanks so much for the answer, its very helpful! Just to clarify does your $m$ variable indicate the mass of the pulley and your $m_1$ variable denotes the mass hanging off the string?

Comment: @Lil_Phil Welcome. $m_1$ is mass of object hanging, while, $m$ is mass of the black dot (We are talking of force acting on some element of pulley, so we must use mass of that element)